# Why do I get different results when I do a manual split of test and train data as opposed to using the Python splitting function

Tags: python, dataframe, modeling

If I run a simple dtree regression model using data via the train_test_split function, I get nice r2 scores, and low mse values.

```
training_data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=['y','x1','x2','x3'])
y = training_data.iloc[:,0]
x = training_data.iloc[:,1:]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 0)  
# fit the regressor with X and Y data 
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

yet if I split the data file manually into two files 2/3 train and 1/3 test. there is a column called human which gives a value 1 to 9 which human it is, i use human 1-6 for training, and 7-9 for test

i get negative r2 scores, and high mse

```
training_data = pandas.read_csv("train"+".csv",usecols=['y','x1','x2','x3'])
testing_data  = pandas.read_csv("test"+".csv", usecols=['y','x1','x2','x3'])

y_train = training_data.iloc[:,training_data.columns.str.contains('y')]
X_train = training_data.iloc[:,training_data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['x1','x2','x3']))] 
y_test = testing_data.iloc[:,testing_data.columns.str.contains('y')]
X_test = testing_data.iloc[:,testing_data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(l_vars))] 

y_train = pandas.Series(y_train['y'], index=y_train.index)
y_test = pandas.Series(y_test['y'], index=y_test.index)

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 0)  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I was expecting more or less the same results, and all the data types seem the same for both calls.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you making the `test.csv` and `train.csv` in the manual example? Is the split exactly the same between the two methods?

Comment: the split I do is manually on the first 2/3rds of the records and last 1/3. the split done by the split function is however it does it internally, so the sets are different but same sizes.... i expect the r2score to be slight different but not to the point it is... it is to do with the types of the objects not the actual data i think

Comment: Why are you doing this: `X_train = training_data.iloc[:, training_data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['x1','x2','x3']))] `? I think that may be leaving you with nothing... have you checked what your `X_train` looks like after that line?      Also, generally, `train_test_split` shuffles the rows in case there is some kind of order in the dataset, to try to get an even distribution of labels.

Comment: no that part works fine

Comment: How do you split data from files? `train_test_split` randomizes the split (samples data uniformly). If you split the file in some specific place you might get unbalanced data (for example if data is ordered by `y`) or other similar problems.

Comment: What is l_vars?

Comment: just ['x1','x2','x3'] i removed the first reference but forgot the 2nd

Comment: I think that the problem is that the split was not Random. For example, let's say you have two labels, 0 and 1. Maybe for a reason, the first file has 90% zeros and 10% ones and the 1/3 file has 100% ones. Then the algorithm will try to predict the 1/3 with minimal knowledge for the ones. So it will give mostly zeros so the accuracy will be very small. The train test split splits the dataset randomly. If you are sure that the split was random then we can search for other problems.

Comment: @BillyBonaros Is on the ball here. You need to randomize your test/train data, or you'll get skewed results.The main question here is why do you want to split your training data manually? It is possible to write a script that randomizes `data.csv` into `train.csv` and `test.csv` but than you might as well use the `train_test_split`

Comment: If you add the parameter `shuffle = False` to `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)` do you get similar results?

Comment: If you post your csvs to a dropbox or in google drive people can confirm their hypothesis and probably be more helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that both methods here actually do what you intend doing and the shapes of your X_train/test and y_train/tests are the same coming from both methods. You can either **plot the underlying distributions of your datasets** or **compare your second implementation against a cross-validated model** (for better rigour).

---

Plot the distributions (i.e. make bar charts/density plots) of the labels (y) in the initial train - test sets vs in the second ones (from the manual implementation). You can dive deeper and also plot your other columns in the data, see if anything about the distributions of your data is different between the resulting sets of the two implementations. If the distributions are different than it makes sense you get discrepancies between your two models. If your discrepancy is huge, it could be your labels (or other columns) are actually sorted for your manual implementation, so then you get very different distributions in the datasets you're comparing.

Also, if you want to make sure that your manual splitting results is a 'representative' set(that would generalise well) based on model results instead of underlying data distributions, I would compare it against the results of a cross-validated model, not one single set of results.

Essentially, although the probability is small and the `train_test_split` does some shuffling, you could essentially get a 'train/test' pair that is performing well just out of luck. (To reduce the chance of that without doing cross validation, I'd suggest making use of the `stratify` argument of the `train_test_split` function. then at least you're sure the first implementation 'tries harder' to get  balanced train/test pairs.)

If you decide to cross validate (with `test_train_split`), you get an average model prediction for the folds and a confidence intervals around it and can check if your second model results fall within that interval. If it doesn't again, it just means your split is actually 'corrupted' somehow (e.g. by having sorted values).

---

P.S. I'd also add that Decision Trees are models that are known to overfit massively [1]. Maybe use a random forest instead? (you should get more stable results due to bootstraping/bagging which would act similarly to cross-validating to reduce the chance of overfitting.)

1 - http://cv.znu.ac.ir/afsharchim/AI/lectures/Decision%20Trees%203.pdf

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry so late in reading. i did check the distributions and they are pretty much identical. the data is basically 9 human beings, and instead of the python split, my manual split is humans 1-6 and test is 7-9 so should be the same representation, i would have thought at least. ill keep digging. I have also done random forests which gives better results on python split, but same issues on my manual split. thanks

Comment: Actually the distributions are very different when doing a manual select of humans 1-6 vs 7-9. When doing the pythom split it does a shuffle as some one mentioned below, and the distributions are near identical. When doing manually they are very different... i would love to post a picture here but the toolbar is missing to do so.. thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 2):

The `train_test_split` function from `scikit-learn` uses `sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit` as per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) and this means, this method randomize your data when splitting.

When you split manually, you didn't randomize it so if your labels is not spreaded evenly throughout your dataset, you'll of course have performance issue since your model won't be generalized enough due to train data not containing enough sample of other labels.

If my suspicion is correct, you should get similar result by passing `shuffle=False` into `train_test_split`.

Comment: train_test_split always returns the same as it sets a random seed, never the less i have done this anyway and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your dataset contains this data.

```
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 2 = 4
4 - 4 = 0
2 - 2 = 0
```

So suppose you want a 50% train split.  train_test_split shuffles it like this so it genaralizes better

```
1+1=2
2-2= 0
```

So it knows what do to when it sees this data

```
2+2
4-4#since it learned both addition and subtraction
```

But when you manually shuffle it like this

```
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 2 =4#only learned addition
```

It doesn't know what do do when it sees this data

```
2 - 2
4 - 4#test data is subtraction
```

Hope this answers you question

Answer (score 0):

It may sound like a simple check but..

In the first example you are reading data from 'data.csv', in the second example you are reading from 'train.csv' and 'test.csv'.  Since you say you split the file manually, I have a question about how that was done.  If you simply cut the file at the 2/3's mark and saved as 'train.csv' and the remaining as 'test.csv' then you have unknowingly made an assumption about the uniformity of the data in the file.  Data files can have an ordered structure which would skew the training or testing, which is why the train_test_split randomizes the rows.  If you haven't already done it, try to randomize the rows first and then write to your train and test csv file to **ensure you have a homogeneous dataset**.

The other line that might be out of place is line 6:

```
X_test = testing_data.iloc[:,testing_data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(l_vars))]
```

Perhaps the l_vars contains something other than what you expect.  Maybe it should read the following to be more consistent.

```
X_test = testing_data.iloc[:,testing_data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['x1','x2','x3']))]
```

good luck, let us know if this helps.